# Prove invariant formula for exterior derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tensors, differential-forms, exterior-derivative

In Marsden "Foundation of Mechanics", it is said that the properties defining the exterior derivative are readily proven to be satisfied by the invariant formula

$d\omega(u)(e_0,...e_k)=\sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^i D\omega(u)·e_i(e_0,...,\hat e_i,...e_k)$

where $e_0,...e_k$ are the basis of the tangent space at point $u$. However, I see no way of proving that this formula satisfies $d(\omega\wedge\rho)=d\omega\wedge\rho + (-1)^k\omega\wedge d\rho$, being $\omega$ a k-form and $\rho$ a m-form, in a coordinate-free way. It seems extremely difficult to prove this property without proving actually that the invariant formula is equal to the coordinate-based definition.

Any clues?

PS: actually, in the book "Manifolds, tensor analysis and applications" by the same author, they don't even try to follow this path and instead prove that both definitions boil down to the coordinate-based one.

Comment: I find your notation very confusing. What's $D\omega$ and what operation is $e_i(e_0,\dotsc,\hat{e_i},\dotsc,e_k)$?

Comment: I find equally confusing the notation $Dw$, but it's verbose from the cited book.

Comment: It’s the differential. Did you perhaps omit a pair of parentheses?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#In_terms_of_invariant_formula. I also recommend write out the formula for $d\omega$, where $\omega$ is just a $1$-form. Once you understand that formula, it's not hard to see how it can be generalized to higher order forms. It's just that the formula for an arbitrary $k$-form is hard to write down in a readable form.